# terrain gen python constraints

Tags: python, game-engine

in my free time I'm making a text-based/ascii(for now) rogue-like game as a study(relevant because context for question)
At the moment, I'm trying to generate the terrain/the rooms that will be used in the world.
The world should be 'endless'.

Generating random terrain isn't the big issue.
I'm struggling with finding a way to maintainably add constraints like:
'plains can not be next to mountain'

I could build a big decisiontree, however, this would mean an if currentTile == plain: if not next to mountain and an if currentTile == mountain: if not text to plains.

this not maintainable, since every rule has to be implemented on 2 places.

I'm wondering what standard solutions for this type of issues exist?

Greetings

Comment: This is not a banal issue dude...

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I'm trying to learn, so I don't mind if it is difficult or challenging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I follow your example excerpt but you could have a list of 2 element sets, each containing disallowed combinations. Then you could look up

```
disallowed = [set(plain, mountains)]
if set(currentTile, newTile) not in disallowed:
    #rest of code
```

Comment: I have to make it disallowed = [set([plain, mountains])]
but that works great. thanks a lot